# How to transfer data from table cell to a new view controller using prepare for segue method?

Tags: parse-platform, swift2, segue

How to use prepare for segue to transfer the images (tweetImg) and date (dateLbl) from tablecell (mainCell) to the Newviewcontroller when I select the cell? in my case I am using parse.com as my backend to retrieve the images and dates data. I am new to programming would appreciate some help, thank you.

***mainVC***

```
import UIKit
class mainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,  {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultsTable: UITableView!

    var resultsStartdateArray = [String]()
    var resultsTweetImageFiles = [PFFile?]()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return resultsTweetImageFiles.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 350
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:mainCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! mainCell
        cell.dateLbl.text = self.resultsStartdateArray[indexPath.row]
      resultsTweetImageFiles[indexPath.row]?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    cell.tweetImg.image = image


                }

            })
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SendDataSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "SendDataSegue")
        {
            let destination: NewViewController =  segue.destinationViewController as! NewViewController
           //  I believe the missing code should be here 
        }
    }
}
```

***mainCell***

```
import UIKit
class mainCell: UITableViewCell {

      @IBOutlet weak var tweetImg: UIImageView!
      @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!

      override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
   }
}
```

***NewViewController***

```
import UIKit

class NewViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var tweetImg: UIImageView!

 var titleString: String!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dateLbl.text = self.titleString

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow i have mentioned a sample template code. organize your code according to bellow mentioned code. important part is select a cell in the `prepareForSegue` instead of in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Which is `let IndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    //Index path is the selected cell  
    let IndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

    //Here you can assign your tweetImg and dateLbl

    let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewViewController
    newViewController.dateLbl.text = //your date label value
    //here assign your image to destination view controller property
}
```

Comment: @ Dimuth Lasantha here is what i have done and it worked : override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let upcoming: NewViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewViewController
    let indexPath = self.resultsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let titleString = self.resultsStartdateArray[indexPath.row] as String
    upcoming.titleString = titleString
    self.resultsTable.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }  how can I perform the segue with a button added to the cell rather than pressing on the cell? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and connect the segue to the table view cell rather than the view controller.

When a cell is selected it's passed as the `sender` parameter in the `prepareForSegue` method.

A side note : Don't perform background tasks in the view – the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method – , do it in the model – the items in the data source array – and then call `reloadData()`